# Application hangs after some time while calculating speed using gps?

Tags: android, geolocation, gps

I am working on application which features a speedometer. It works fine for about 15-20 minutes but after that the app hangs and freezes. What would be reason?

I have written a separate class for GPS data called `GPSManager` from which I call a method `onGPSUpdate()`  which is overridden in `MainActivity`. In that method, all calculations for speed and location are done.

Below is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements    OnPageChangeListener,GPSCallback,OnClickListener 
{

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
     {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        gpsManager = new GPSManager();
        gpsManager.startListening(getApplicationContext());
        gpsManager.setGPSCallback(this);
     }
    public void onGPSUpdate(Location location) 
    {
        String directionString = "NORTH";
        float speedDigital = 0 ;

          if (location.hasSpeed())
          {
            speedDigital = location.getSpeed();

            final String speedString = "" + roundDecimal(convertSpeed(speedDigital),2);
            setSpeedText(R.id.textViewSpeed,speedString);
            if (location.hasBearing())
            {

              int bearingAngle = (int) location.getBearing();
              if ((bearingAngle > 337.5D) || (bearingAngle <= 22.5D))
                  directionString = "NORTH " + bearingAngle;
              if ((bearingAngle > 22.5D) && (bearingAngle <= 67.5D))
                  directionString = "N-EAST  "+ bearingAngle;
              if ((bearingAngle > 67.5D) && (bearingAngle <= 112.5D))
                  directionString = "EAST "+ bearingAngle;
              if ((bearingAngle > 112.5D) && (bearingAngle <= 157.5D))
                  directionString = "S-EAST "+ bearingAngle;
              if ((bearingAngle > 157.5D) && (bearingAngle <= 202.5D))
                  directionString = "SOUTH "+ bearingAngle;
              if ((bearingAngle > 202.5D) && (bearingAngle <= 247.5D))
                  directionString = "S-WEST "+ bearingAngle;
              if ((bearingAngle > 247.5D) && (bearingAngle <= 292.5D))
                  directionString = "WEST "+ bearingAngle;
              if ((bearingAngle > 292.5D) && (bearingAngle <= 337.5D))
                  directionString = "N-WEST "+ bearingAngle;
            }
            textViewCompass.setText(directionString);
          }
          else{
              setSpeedText(R.id.textViewSpeed, "0.0");
          }
            Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
            List<Address> addresses = null;
            try {
                        textViewLocation.setText(currentLocation);
                        textViewLocation.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                         }
            } 
            catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
     }
         private void setSpeedText(int textid,String text){
        Double val = Double.parseDouble(text);
        Integer intVal = val.intValue(); 
        TextView tv = ((TextView)findViewById(textid));
        tv.setText(""+intVal);
    }
    }
    public class GPSManager{
          private static final int gpsMinTime = 1000;
          private static final int gpsMinDistance = 0; 
        private static LocationManager locationManager = null;
        private static LocationListener locationListener = null;
        private static GPSCallback gpsCallback = null;

        public GPSManager(){       
                GPSManager.locationListener = new LocationListener(){
                        @Override
                        public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {        
                            if(GPSManager.gpsCallback != null){ 
                                GPSManager.gpsCallback.onGPSUpdate(location);
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onProviderDisabled(final String provider){
                            Log.v("gps provider disabled ", provider);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onProviderEnabled(final String provider){
                            Log.v("gps provider enabled",provider);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onStatusChanged(final String provider, final int status, final Bundle extras){
                            Log.v("gps provider ststus", ""+status);
                        }
                };
        }
        public GPSCallback getGPSCallback() {
                return GPSManager.gpsCallback;
        }

        public void setGPSCallback(final GPSCallback gpsCallback){
                GPSManager.gpsCallback = gpsCallback;
        }

        public void startListening(final Context context) {
                if (GPSManager.locationManager == null){
                        GPSManager.locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                }
            GPSManager.locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0L, 0.0F, GPSManager.locationListener); 
            };

        public void stopListening() {
                try {
                        if (GPSManager.locationManager != null && GPSManager.locationListener != null) {
                                GPSManager.locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSManager.locationListener);
                        }
                        GPSManager.locationManager = null;
                }
                catch (final Exception ex){
                }
        }}
```

Comment: Could you get a hold of your logcat? That would explain the crash.

Comment: Ya I was trying to get logcat for that using logcat apps while driving .

Comment: You might want to look into ACRA or Crittercism to automatically collect the logs in a crash, especially when testing the app outside where you don't have access to a computer. aLogcat could be dangerous while driving.

Comment: Hi, I have implemented Crittercism for crash report. I tested application got popup of Aplication is not responsding then I closed it by OK but still i didnt got any mail for crash. Is it compulsory that application should be on play store ??

Comment: No it's not. You might want to email crittercism about the bug, I'm not entirely sure how fast the crash should be emailed. But sometimes I've even received the email before the Application crashed dialog.